# Javascript adding a number to a textbox with a button

Tags: javascript

Maybe a dumb question but i am trying to grab a number that is in a textbox and add 1 to it by pressing a button.

Here is the html

```
<input type="text" id="txt_invoer" value="1">
<button onclick="countUp()">+</button>
<button onclick="countDown()">-</button>
```

Here is the javascript

```
<script>
    function countUp() {
        var i = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt_invoer').value);
        var iResult = i++;
        document.getElementById('txt_invoer').innerHTML = 
        iResult.toString();
    }
</script>
```

I hope im not being too dumb...
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `.value = iResult`

Comment: change from `var iResult = i++;` to `var iResult= ++i;`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow buddy!

Just use the DOM element's `.value` field to update an input's value. `innerHTML` could be used to update a div's content or such.

Also `i++` increments the value but returns the value of `i` before being incremented, so you should be using `++i` to return the incremented value.

```js
function countUp() {
    var txtInvoer = document.getElementById('txt_invoer');
    var i = parseInt(txtInvoer.value, 10);
    txtInvoer.value = ++i;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_invoer" value="1">
<button onclick="countUp()">+</button>
<button onclick="countDown()">-</button>
```

Comment: Please chose to close such questions instead of answering. Its a bad practice to answer a dupe

Comment: Thank you very much that is working! :-)

Comment: So please mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

When doing i++; the assignment of value is done before increment. So that's why a lot of people is using ++i. Where assignment is done after increment.

I suggest you to solutions :

- ++i;
- i += 1; // short method of i = i + 1;

I mostly recommend the second. A lot of people doesn't know this, so i didn't encourage to use ++ to disable any risk of mistake.

Have a look here for Mozilla documentation about ++ : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()

Comment: 1+, what you are saying is also encouraged by airbnb's javascirpt guide: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables--unary-increment-decrement

Comment: Yeah I didn't included it, but you're true. It's encouraged by a lot of big companies.